# Angular- How to route parent/child with repeated component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to set up my Angular routing.

I have a parent route, and inside as a child, I'd like to repeat the same component multiple times (a list of all the locations). Each of the location (child) component occurrences will look the same, just with different data that I will need to pass in. (I'll do this with *ngFor).

Here's what I'm thinking so far:

```
<router-outlet>//for the parent 

    <router-outlet name="aux">
         <ul *ngFor="let location in service.locations"
    </router-outlet>
       //where I list out all the locations^

</router-outlet>
```

on my app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent }, //lists all locations
  { path: 'locations/:id', component: LocationsComponent }, //view 1 
    location
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/main},
];
```

(I want to have both parent and child appear on initial load. Should I modify that?^)

Now this is the part I don't understand as much, I need to set my route configs. Is this close? And does it goin my app-routing.module.ts file as well?

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/', name: 'MainPath', component: MainComponent, 
   useAsDefault: true},
  {aux:'/auxRoute', name: 'AuxPath', component: SecondComponent}
])
```

Thanks! Please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: How does your data change? do you mean likes /route/item/1354?

Comment: Location id just increases by one, and each location has a different name, coordinates, etc that I want to display as if it were a table on my main route. Just each row is one occurrence of the location component. Click on one location to go to 'location/:id'